# Как получить данные из див через javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как получить данные из див через javascript? Не могу получить данные только `А` и `В` без `span`

```js
$('.divs').on('click', '.div', function() {
  var data = $(this, '.word').text();
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

```css
.div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <div class="div">
    <div class="word">A</div>
    <span>Word A</span>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <div class="word">B</div>
    <span>Word B</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема только в порядке аргументов. Если используем `$('.word', this)` вместо `$(this, '.word')`, то работает:

```js
$('.divs').on('click', '.div', function() {
  var data = $('.word', this).text();
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

```css
.div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <div class="div">
    <div class="word">A</div>
    <span>Word A</span>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <div class="word">B</div>
    <span>Word B</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```